# Synchronization of Emails

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm

If I delete Emails from Dynamics CRM which were tracked from Outlook, will that particular Email get deleted in Outlook as well?

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a tracked email message in Outlook does not delete the email message from Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Deleting an email message in Microsoft Dynamics CRM does not delete the tracked message from Outlook.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/deleting-records-that-have-been-tracked-with-crm-for-outlook.aspx

Comment: Thanks Andrius,
I too was able to find this later after I posted this question. Thanks a lot for your help again.